# android:unable to start activity component info

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I start the intent to go to the next activity. I get the above error. I am not able to go to the next activity(see SecondActivity.java below).

My MainActivity is:

```
package com.example.testflashfile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button nextButton;
    Button playButton;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(),new MyGestureDetector());
        View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        playButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent startAnimation=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayAnimationActivity.class);
                startAnimation.putExtra("SWF_NAME","a");
                startActivity(startAnimation);
            }
        });


        TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytext);
        helloTxt.setText(readTxt());
        nextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private String readTxt(){

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textone);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    } 



    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener 
    {


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //  left to right  swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }



    }

}
```

The second activity is as follows:

```
package com.example.testflashfile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    Button nextButton2;
    Button backButton2;
    Button playButton2;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    GestureDetector gestureDetector; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(),new MyGestureDetector());
        View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytexttwo);
        helloTxt.setText(readTxt());
        nextButton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nexttwo);
        nextButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        playButton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent startAnimation=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,PlayAnimationActivity.class);
                startAnimation.putExtra("SWF_NAME","b");
                startActivity(startAnimation);
            }
        });

        backButton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backtwo);
        backButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    private String readTxt(){

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.texttwo);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }


    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener 
    {


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Intent i= new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //  left to right  swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                Intent i= new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }



    }
}
```

I don't understand where am going wrong here. I have checked similar threads on stack overflow related to this error. But the explanation was not that clear. Any help/Suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking your time out to read such a lengthy post.

the log cat is:

```
03-11 10:03:18.599: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 66K, 52% free 2585K/5379K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 92ms
03-11 10:03:18.729: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
03-11 10:03:18.729: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testflashfile/com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:2729)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:35)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 10:03:18.749: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
03-11 10:03:21.539: I/Process(336): Sending signal. PID: 336 SIG: 9
03-11 12:37:51.179: D/dalvikvm(382): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 67K, 53% free 2581K/5379K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 199ms
03-11 12:37:51.478: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
03-11 12:37:51.479: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testflashfile/com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:2729)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:35)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 12:37:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more
03-11 12:37:57.159: I/Process(382): Sending signal. PID: 382 SIG: 9
03-11 12:40:41.579: W/ActivityThread(418): Application com.example.testflashfile is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-11 12:40:41.649: I/System.out(418): Sending WAIT chunk
03-11 12:40:42.381: I/dalvikvm(418): Debugger is active
03-11 12:40:42.499: I/System.out(418): Debugger has connected
03-11 12:40:42.499: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:42.703: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:43.011: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:43.209: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:43.419: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:43.619: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:43.869: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:44.070: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:44.269: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:44.469: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:44.720: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:44.925: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:45.140: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:45.339: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:45.559: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:45.793: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:46.031: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:46.261: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:46.468: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:46.669: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:46.875: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-11 12:40:47.109: I/System.out(418): debugger has settled (1505)
03-11 12:49:24.089: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 68K, 52% free 2583K/5379K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 212ms
03-11 12:51:01.819: D/AndroidRuntime(418): Shutting down VM
03-11 12:51:01.839: W/dalvikvm(418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testflashfile/com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:69)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 12:51:07.499: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  ... 11 more
03-11 12:56:07.749: I/Process(418): Sending signal. PID: 418 SIG: 9
03-11 14:17:47.570: D/dalvikvm(457): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 68K, 53% free 2581K/5379K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 116ms
03-11 14:17:47.699: D/AndroidRuntime(457): Shutting down VM
03-11 14:17:47.699: W/dalvikvm(457): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testflashfile/com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:44)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 14:17:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  ... 11 more
```

The manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testflashfile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
         />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.testflashfile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.testflashfile.SecondActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
         <activity android:name="com.example.testflashfile.ThirdActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
          <activity android:name="com.example.testflashfile.FourthActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
          <activity android:name="com.example.testflashfile.FifthActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

<activity android:name="com.example.testflashfile.PlayAnimationActivity"
               android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your complete Logcat output

Comment: is your second activity marked in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Post your Logcat and manifest please.

Comment: yes it is mentioned in the manifest. I have used intents before. this is the first time am facing this problem.

Comment: Log cat and manifest has been posted @sebastian

Comment: Logcat and manifest has been posted @staaar

Comment: I tried your answer @Pragnan. application is force closed when i do that. It doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys my problem is solved. But I cant seem to pin point where exactly my code was wrong. But I will like to update you guys about what worked for me(there may be a better solution than this. feel free to edit this post any time).

Here is my MainActivity now:

```
package com.example.testflashfile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import com.example.testflashfile.GlobalVariables;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button nextButton;
    Button playButton;
    Button backButton;


    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytext);
        helloTxt.setText(readTxt());


        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(),new MyGestureDetector());
        View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        playButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent startAnimation=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayAnimationActivity.class);
                startAnimation.putExtra("SWF_NAME","a");
                startActivity(startAnimation);
            }
        });



        nextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private String readTxt(){

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textone);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    } 



    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //  left to right  swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }



    }

}
```

Here is the SecondActivity:

```
package com.example.testflashfile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{
    Button nextButton,backButton,playButton;
    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytexttwo);
        helloTxt.setText(readTxt());


        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(),new MyGestureDetector());
        View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainViewtwo);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        playButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.playtwo);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent startAnimation=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,PlayAnimationActivity.class);
                startAnimation.putExtra("SWF_NAME","b");
                startActivity(startAnimation);
            }
        });



        nextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nexttwo);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backtwo);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private String readTxt(){

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.texttwo);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    } 

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Intent i= new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //  left to right  swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                Intent i= new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

I created a Global Varibles class for my activities as they were using the same varibales in swipe method

package com.example.testflashfile;

public class GlobalVariables {

```
static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
```

}

This change somehow solved my problem. I still don't know how. But this is what worked.

I would like to know what is the actual reason behind this working. For now the code works and am moving on.

Thanks all for the help and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
'screenOrientation="portrait'  from tag for second  activity in  your manifest . you already set orientation property of activity before call request... methods.

Comment: Manifest is posted. and is fine in my opinion. What does this snippet do? it gives me errors such as "Syntax error on token "void", @ expected"

Comment: that is not an error. but i did as u told. its still giving me the same error.